# how to get if person is already liked fb page or not using javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I intergrate like button in my website. After login with facebook, now if any one already liked fb page directly from facebook then some fields will be shown to user otherwise fields will be hidden. I already put function for above thing and it works for me but not for others. Don't know why?
Here is a function which contains fb like thing and triggered on button click

```
function getUserDetail(){

 FB.api("me/likes/242500342443159", function(response) {
if ( response.data.length == 1 ) { 
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    getUserInfo();
    document.getElementById("note").style.display="none";
    console.log('You like it');
} else {
$('#myModal').modal('show');
    getUserInfo();
    document.getElementById("form").style.display="none";
    console.log("You don't like it");
}
  });
  }
```

and i also took user_likes permission on login.
 Please correct me if i am doing any mistake in above function.

Comment: also I get confirm text on click like button. there is any solution to remove that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMPORTANT: You are not allowed to hide/gate content behind a like or incentivize liking a Page in any way. you must read the platform policy before creating any App: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/**

That being said, you would need `user_likes` for that API call, which needs to get reviewed by Facebook before everyone can use it. Without review, only users with a role in the App are able to authorize that permission. It is called Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: oh due to adiminstrator role i got like status. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you got permission for your application, and got premission from the logged in user, but it still doesn't work I would sugest creating error handling and in case of debugging log the response object.

Check for error codes and response format: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/

Comment: it doesn't get like response and show **"You don't like it"** in console , even a person liked that fb page. But it works fine for me.

Comment: @VirendraSingh, could you please share the complete code?